# Php : Post form does not work

Tags: php, html

Ok so i'm working in a callcenter and we have a monitor that shows the breaks every caller has taken. I'm new to this company and have gotton the assignment to make a website for this monitor.

below is my php code. 
I have searched for houres on what might be the problem but i can't seem to find it.

The problem is : if i click the button then my form doesnt get posted and doesnt write to csv. The code has worked before so in the main lines I know my code is correct. It must be something silly and small but I just can't find it.

My code :

```
<html>
<head>
<LINK REL="StyleSheet" HREF="Input_form.css">
<title>Verander Plaatsindeling</title>
<h1><center>Verander plaatsindeling<center></h1>
<hr/>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(ISSET($_POST['submitMe']))
        {
        $csv = fopen("zitplaatsenAntwerpen.csv","w") or die("Kan csv niet vinden!");

        for($counter=1;$counter<=30;$counter++)
        {
            $naam = $_POST["Naam" .$counter];
            $project = $_POST["Project" .$counter];
            $csvrow = $counter . ";" . $naam . ";" . $project . "\n";
            fwrite($csv, $csvrow);
        }
    ?>
     <?php
            fclose($csv);
            echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            <!--
            window.alert('Gegevens ingeladen!')
            // -->
            </SCRIPT>";
            $informatie = array();
            $f = fopen("ZitplaatsenAntwerpen.csv","r") or die("Kan csv niet vinden!");

            while (!feof($f))
            {
                $arrM = explode(";",fgets($f));
                $informatie[$arrM[0]]["Nummer"] = ucwords($arrM[0]);
                $informatie[$arrM[0]]["Naam"] = ucwords($arrM[1]);
                $informatie[$arrM[0]]["Project"] = ucwords($arrM[2]);
            }
            fclose($f);
        }
        else
        {
            $informatie = array();
            $f = fopen("ZitplaatsenAntwerpen.csv", "r")  or die("Kan csv niet vinden!");

            while (!feof($f))
            {
            $arrM = explode(";",fgets($f));
            $informatie[$arrM[0]]["Nummer"] = ucwords($arrM[0]);
            $informatie[$arrM[0]]["Naam"] = ucwords($arrM[1]);
            $informatie[$arrM[0]]["Project"] = ucwords($arrM[2]);
            }
            fclose($f);
        }
     ?>
     <div style="word-spacing:7em;" align:center>
      Nummer    Naam    Project
     </div>

    <pre><form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
    <?php
        for ($teller = 1;$teller<=30; $teller++)
        {
                if(!empty($informatie[$teller]))
                {
                    echo "<div align:center>";
                    echo  "     " . $teller . "   ";
                    echo "<input type='text' name='Naam" .$teller. "' value='";
                    echo $informatie[$teller]["Naam"] . "'>";
                    echo "<input id='" .$teller. "' ";
                    echo "<input type='text' name='Project" .$teller. "' value='";
                    echo $informatie[$teller]["Project"] . "'>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<div align:center>";
                    echo "      " . $teller . "   ";
                    echo "<input type='text' name='Naam" .$teller. "' value='";
                    echo $informatie[$teller]["Naam"] . "'>";
                    echo "<input id='" .$teller. "' ";
                    echo "<input type='text' name='Project" .$teller. "' value='";
                    echo $informatie[$teller]["Project"] . "'>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
        }
    ?>
    </form></pre>
<div align="center">
<button style="width:100;height:50" type="submit" name="submitMe">Opslaan</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this PHP

```
if(ISSET($_POST['submitMe']))
```

with this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitMe']))
```

You have put your submit button after the closed form try to make something like this:

```
<input type="submit" style="width:100;height:50"  name="submitMe" value="Opslaan">
</form>
```

Comment: Ahh god ... I looked over that for 4 houres lol... 
Thanks so much matey

Answer (score 1):

Your submit button is outside of your `<form>` tag. Look at the source of your page and you will notice it is rendered as:

```
<form>
....
</form>
<button...>
```

The `button` should live inside the form tags as:

```
<form>
<button ...>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong,

```
<button style="width:100;height:50" type="submit" name="submitMe">Opslaan</button>
```

You should use

```
<input style="width:100;height:50" type="submit" name="submitMe" value="Opslaan" />
```